# Laravel add action on rowdata (server side action)

Tags: php, laravel

I have generated Laravel Code with quickAdminpanel.

However, I would like to add a action to each row of a table, which generates a print job on the server. I tried a few things but I am not sure what is the propper way of extending the application to support this porpperly:

1. each row should get the "action" button
2. once clicked, server side code shuld get executed (generating the job and putting into the queue)
3. ideally, a modal is shown to confirm this has been done

What I did so far: I modified `resources/views/admin/table/index.blade.php` to add the button I need, now this is to get the action (routing, controller etc.?) set up.

Sorry, this is a poor beginners question :-(

Thanks for any feedback and help!

[modified table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brw1H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's in the documentation:

https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/how-to-customize-vieweditdelete-buttons-column-in-ajax-datatables/

You can find the bit you are looking for under `Customization 2. Add or Remove buttons.`

--

There is also a list of other useful links in the documentation:

https://helpdocs.quickadminpanel.com/customizing-the-code/datatables-customizations

Comment: Thanks. This is quite usefull, however, I followed that and have the buttons in the view already. But my question really is the part not covered in this tutorial as I need to understand how I can add a new action. They mention there Controller, Routes but I could not get this work or find a step-by-step tutorial on this.
In this specific example they mention to add an "export" action but not go into how to do that.